# Dates in dd/mm/yyyy format return 1004 Error in Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba, date, xirr

I have this code, and it works:

```
Sub try3()
Dim dates(1 To 2) As Date
Dim values(1 To 2) As Double
Dim TIR As Double

dates(1) = #1/1/2015#
dates(2) = #1/1/2016#

values(1) = -1000
values(2) = 1101

TIR = Application.WorksheetFunction.xirr(values, dates)

End Sub
```

However, if I change the dates, for example, to

```
dates(1) = #1/15/2015#
dates(2) = #1/15/2016#
```

, then I get an error 1004:

> "Property Xirr of class WorksheetFuntion could not be obtained".

My computer date format is european (dd/mm/yyyy). If I change it to american (mm/dd/yyyy), then my code works.

I would like to keep the european format in my system, and I would like my code to be runnable from any computer, regardless of their system's date format

I have tried to define the dates as follows, but I get the same error.

```
dates(1) = DateSerial(2015, 1, 15)
dates(2) = DateSerial(2016, 1, 15)
```

Any idea how to make VBA understand dates while keeping the european format in my computer?

Thank you

Comment: Strange... the code you have provided works for me (Excel 2016, v.16.0.1.., 64-bit) . The three different versions following works for me: 1. `dates(1) = #1/15/2015#` 2. `dates(1) = DateSerial(2015, 1, 15)` 3. `dates(1) = CDate("2015-01-15")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the `XIRR()`, it is doing its best:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim TIR As Double
    TIR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Xirr(Array(-1000, 1101), Array(42019, 42384))
    Debug.Print TIR

End Sub
```

Just try to cast to `Long` with `CLng`, whichever date you are working with, it should return `42019` and `42384` in Excel, if you are not using the `Date1904` "feature".

Comment: I like the idea of converting dates to integers, but I´m facing the same problem of getting VBA to understand the dates. How do I go from "15/01/2015" to "42019"? I have tried this, but won´t work:          dates(1) = CLng("1/15/2015")

Comment: @David R - at least you are narrowing down the question, eliminating the XIRR() from the picture. Can you try CLng("01/15/2015"). The settings seem strange.

Comment: I solved it by 1) introducing the dates as Long instead of Dates. 2) Getting the dates from excel (through Range.Value) instead of typing them in the code

Comment: @DavidR - congrats! :) You may even consider getting the dates as `Range.Value2` and parsing them to `Date()` immediately. In the general case it should work. The `Long` was just a proposed workaround to see the locate the real problem.